# How to mix JSON-serialized Django models with flat JSON

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

The problem I'm having is with mixing serialized Django models using django.core.serializers with some other piece of data and then trying to serialize the entire thing using json.dumps.

Example code:

```
scores  = []
for indicator in indicators:
    score_data = {}
    score_data["indicator"] = serializers.serialize("json", [indicator,])
    score_data["score"] = evaluation.indicator_percent_score(indicator.id)
    score_data["score_descriptor"] = \
        serializers.serialize("json", 
            [form.getDescriptorByPercent(score_data["score"]),], 
            fields=("order", "value", "title"))
    scores.append(score_data)
scores = json.dumps(scores)

return HttpResponse(scores)
```

Which returns a list of objects like this:

```
{
    indicator: "{"pk": 345345, "model": "forms.indicator", "fields": {"order": 1, "description": "Blah description.", "elements": [10933, 4535], "title": "Blah Title"}}",
    score: 37.5,
    score_descriptor: "{"pk": 66666, "model": "forms.descriptor", "fields": {"order": 1, "value": "1.00", "title": "Unsatisfactory"}}"
}
```

The problem I'm having can be seen in the JSON with the  serialized Django models being wrapped in multiple sets of quotations. This makes the it very hard to work with on the client side as when I try to do something like

```
indicator.fields.order
```

it evaluates to nothing because the browser thinks I'm dealing with a string of some sort.

Ideally I would like valid JSON without the conflicting quotations that make it unreadable. Something akin to a list of objects like this:

```
{
    indicator: {
        pk: 12931231,
        fields: {
            order: 1,
            title: "Blah Title",
        }
    },
    etc.
 }
```

Should I be doing this in a different order, using a different data structure, different serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution involved dropping the use of `django.core.serializers` and instead using `django.forms.model_to_dict` and `django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder`.

The resulting code looked like this:

```
for indicator in indicators:
    score_data = {}
    score_data["indicator"] = model_to_dict(indicator)
    score_data["score"] = evaluation.indicator_percent_score(indicator.id)
    score_data["score_descriptor"] = \
        model_to_dict(form.getDescriptorByPercent(score_data["score"]), 
            fields=("order", "value", "title"))

    scores.append(score_data)
scores = json.dumps(scores, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

The problem seemed to arise from the fact that I was essentially serializing the Django models twice. Once with the `django.core.serializers` function and once with the `json.dumps` function.

The solution solved this by converting the model to a dictionary first, throwing it in the dictionary with the other data and then serializing it once using the `json.dumps` using the `DjangoJSONEncoder`.

Hope this helps someone out because I couldn't find my specific issue but was able to piece it together using other answer to other stackoverflow posts.